# Redisplay list after clearing search bar

Tags: javascript, searchbar

I created a searchbar on my site. It's displays the results of a list (items of that list are populated from a DB with PHP). When I press the back button on my keyboard, all is going well and my list is displayed again. I would like to have that when I clear the searchbar field automatically with JavaScript. So if I do:

```
function clear(el) {
    el.value.text = "";
}
```

, my list shoud be displayed again with all the items.

The HTML of my searchbar is:

```
<input type="text" id="searchBar" onkeyup="search()" onfocusout="clear(this)" />
```

How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.